# How to make Drupal work without PDO

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, pdo

How could Drupal be made to work on a MySQL database without PDO being used?

I have a MySQL database and PHP 5.3 however PDO is permanently disabled (I cannot change it). Is there an extension or module I could use with Drupal so it doesn't need PDO?

Thanks in advance.

P.s. I am new to Drupal.

Comment: I think you're in trouble... Drupal without PDO sounds bad.

Comment: PDO permanently disabled sounds bad too...

Comment: There is a userland PDO emulation for PHP4 and PHP5. Maybe that would be a workaround for you as well. See //xpdo.org/ (You have to download it from the horrid code dump linked there bottom right, which shall not be named here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://drupal.org/requirements) you can find requirements for Drupal.

They say :

> Drupal 7: MySQL 5.0.15 or higher with PDO, PostgreSQL 8.3 or higher
>   with PDO, SQLite 3.3.7 or higher

So if you're using MySQL, you have no other choice than using PDO.

You can see [here](http://drupal.org/requirements/pdo) all ways to install it.

Comment: I'm not the one who voted you down, but the OP already said that they can't install PDO.

Comment: I am sorry. That looks like install Linux without a kernel or a Windows game without DirectX.

Comment: Welcome to GoDaddy hosting :P